# Find out when multiple threads are finished

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose we have this scenario:

In a database, there are Car1, Car2, Car3.
To get these objects, we will do three queries. But, instead doing :

```
Car car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar1();
Car car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar2();
Car car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar3();
```

I need them to run parallel(for performance issues) :

```
Task<Car> car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar1();
Task<Car> car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar2();
Task<Car> car1 = await ApiHelper.GetCar3();
```

Now is the question: what is the best practice to find out that all Tasks are completed ?

Comment: using `await` here will "block" the containing method.

Comment: Try `Task.WaitAll(car1,car2,car3);`